# Monodevelop / Mac - cycle open documents

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, monodevelop

Environment is MonoDevelop 3.1.1 / Mac OS X 10.8.2 / Macbook Pro w/North American English keyboard

What keyboard shortcut cycles forward/backward through open documents?

I saw this [document](http://kureus.com/2011/02/26/monodevelop-keyboard-shortcuts/) which seems to suggest <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>PgDn</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>PgUp</kbd>, however it doesn't work for me (on a laptop as described, so I used <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>DownArrow</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>UpArrow</kbd>).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Xamarin Studio 4.0 on OSX 10.8.2, the keyboard shortcuts for switching between tabs (representing open documents) are *Option + Command + LeftArrow* and *Option + Command + RightArrow*.

Xamarin Studio is based on MonoDevelop, so the keyboard shortcuts might be the same.

Comment: Interesting... I'm using Xamarin Studio now, although it does seem to be the same in MD too. However, the shortcut you mention is listed as 'Navigate Forward/Backward', and seems to take my backward and forward through my 'navigation history'. I'm not quite sure what 'navigation history' is, but it's more than just tabs - it seems to be navigating me both between tabs (although not necessarily in the order they are open) as well as to locations *within* tabs...

Answer (score 0):

As of MonoDevelop 4.0, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> allows you to cycle through open tabs/documents (in both Windows and Mac environments).